# Python how to remove header when sending an email?

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtplib

I am trying to remove the header section, currently the received email looks like this:

[image: Email Screenshot].

I don't want it to be displayed when the receiver gets the email, I am not sure how to hide it.

I tried to just delete it but received an error. That code is included but commented out below.

```
import donator
import csv
import os
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


def ReadEmailTemplate():
    oFile = open('EmailTemplate.txt', 'r')
    Subject = oFile.readline()
    Body = oFile.read()
    return [Subject, Body]

def ReadCSVFile():
    with open('ExampleData.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        allDonators = []
        for line in csv_reader:
            Number = line[0]
            Name = line[1]
            Amount = line[2]
            Date = line[3]
            Mode = line[4]
            Email = line[5]
            allDonators.append(donator.Donator(Number, Name, Amount, Date, Mode, Email))
    return allDonators

txt = ReadEmailTemplate()
Subject = txt[0]
Body = txt[1]

# READ VALUES FROM CSV FILE AND RUN THROUGH THEM
allDonators = ReadCSVFile()

# CREATE EMAIL WITH THOSE VALUES
for donator in allDonators:
    print(f'Sending email to: {donator.Name} at {donator.Email}...')
    msg = EmailMessage()
    Body = MIMEText(
        Body.replace('REPLACE_DATE', donator.Date).replace('DONATION_AMOUNT', donator.Amount).replace('DONATION_DATE',
                                                                                                      donator.Date))
    msg.set_content(Body)
    msg['From'] = os.environ['PERS_EMAIL']
    msg['To'] = donator.Email
    msg['Subject'] = Subject.replace('CUSTOMER_NAME', donator.Name)
    print(msg.get('Content-Type'))
    print(msg.get('Content-Transfer-Encoding'))
    print(msg.get('MIME-Version'))
    #for hdr in ['Content-Type', 'Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'MIME-Version']:
    #    del msg[hdr]
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
        smtp.login(os.environ['PERS_EMAIL'], os.environ['PERS_EMAILPW'])
        smtp.sendmail(os.environ['PERS_EMAIL'], donator.Email, msg.as_string())
    

smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465).quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ReadEmailTemplate`, you have `Subject = oFile.readline()`.  `file.readline()` leaves the newline `'\n'` in the line.  So, your subject line is followed by a blank line, which terminates the headers, and the rest of the headers are seen as message.  Just do

```
Subject = oFile.readline().strip()
```

Note that you don't have to split out the fields of your CSV:

```
    for line in csv_reader:
        allDonators.append(donator.Donator(*line))
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! That perfectly solves my issue. I also did not know about splitting on the fields. That will be really helpful across all my projects!